# Difficulty with Printf statements anf For loops in code

Tags: c, linux, for-loop, printf

This is the code I've written for this [HackerEarth Problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/feasible-relations/) and In my code If I remove printf statements and nested for loops then I get correct output but If I keep them I get wrong answer.What is wrong in the code??

Please help me solve this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>

int flag=0;
int main()
{
int test;
scanf("%d",&test);
while(test--)
{
    int var=0,rel=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&var,&rel);

    int arr[var+1][10005];
    int not[rel][2];        

    int n1,n2,n=0,i;
    char s[3];
    flag=0;
    for(i=0;i<var+1;i++)
    {   
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<10005;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=0;
        }   
    }
    for(i=0;i<rel;i++)
    {
        not[i][0]=0;
        not[i][1]=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<rel;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %s %d",&n1,s,&n2);
        if(s[0]=='=')
        {   
            arr[n1][(arr[n1][0]++)+1]=n2;
            arr[n2][(arr[n2][0]++)+1]=n1;
        }   
        else
        {
            not[n][0]=n1;
            not[n][1]=n2;
            n++;
        }   
    }   

    int j;


    ***/*Problem Is With This For Loops and Print Statements*/
    for(i=0;i<var+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /*Upto This Point*/***  


    int visit[var];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        flag=0;
        dfs(arr,visit,not[i][0],not[i][1]);
        if(flag==1)
        {
            printf("NO\n");
            break;
        }

    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        printf("YES\n");
    }

    for(i=0;i<var+1;i++)
    {
        arr[i][0]=0;
    }

    }
}


void dfs(int arr[][10005],int visit[],int start,int find)
{
    if(arr[start][0]==0 || visit[start]==1)
        return;

    visit[start]=1;

    while(arr[start][0]!=0)
    {
        int next=arr[start][arr[start][0]];
        arr[start][0]--;

        if(next==find)
        {
            flag=1;
        }
        dfs(arr,visit,next,find);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `flag==1` ever? I see nothing that set `flag=1` IIUC, the NO is never reached.

Comment: dfs() function is changing flag to 1 if match is found and prints output NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visit` array is the culprit.

It is an un-initialized auto variable (allocated on stack).
And among first things in `dfs` it is being *read*.

Thus, the output of `dfs` and the value of `flag` therof is random!

The code block you recognized as making a difference is just changing content of the stack and from this it just "happens" to work if the code is in.

So, please initialize `visit` before calling `dfs`.

Comment: Thanks Dude It Worked...

Answer (score 1):

It is quite obvious that the judger only accepts "YES" or "NO" as the answer, the code you print the data are only debug codes, they should not be submitted as part of your solution.

Comment: I know that But problem is that its not showing correct output in compiler on my pc if I remove printf statement

Comment: @Trevor_V Can you post the output on your pc and the expected output as well?

Comment: Output If I keep Printf and For loops[And this is the right output]                                                                                                    NO
YES
NO
NO
YES
NO
YES
NO
NO
YES                                                                                                            Output If I comment Printf And For loop which gives wrong ans            NO
YES
YES
YES
YES
NO
YES
YES
NO
YES